# Android: Getting sound resource (R.raw.sound) from a class you created

Tags: java, android, runtime, media-player, r.java-file

Hi I'm getting an error that resource can't be found. There is no gradle error, it was able to compile. But during runtime - resource can't be found.

What I did was:

1. ClassA - that has the getter and setter for int variable sound
2. ClassB - passing the data - int - R.raw.sound
3. ClassActivity - retrieving the data and passing it to the MediaPlayer object as the soundObject variable

   ```
   //Class Activity
   int soundObject;
   ClassB classB = new ClassB();

   //to access the ClassA, I have a method in ClassB that enables me to access it - name getClassA(int soundNumber);

   ClassA classA = classB.getClassB(0);

   soundObject = classA.getSoundResource();
   MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundObject);

   sound.start()
   ```

What is wrong with what I did? Should I refer it to Resource instead of it. I initially tried doing Resource, but Android Studio suggested me to use int instead.

Comment: You need to initialise `soundObject` to the appropriate resource.

Comment: @akash93, i have initialised it in ClassB already and i'm just trying to pull the data out of ClassB and pass it to the variable soundObject.

Comment: But the `soundObject` you are passing to the MediaPlayer is not the one you initialised in ClassB if this is the entire code.. `soundObject` inside your ClassActivity refers to a new variable whose value has to be set. I may be missing something but that is all I can infer from the code you've posted.

Comment: @akash93, i missed adding it on the code. But I have updated it.